# What am I doing wrong with the CSS here? Everything else is going on the sides

Tags: html, css

Just spent some while doing this site, now when im trying to add a footer or something above this container i got, everything gets on the side of my container. When i delete this css code it works but then i get other issues, is the problem here or is there a way to get around this?

```
body {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
min-height: 100vh;
background: white;
```

}

When I delete this I get it to work but for responsiveness i need it, like my nav menu is ending up beside this etc etc. Tell me if you need more.

Sending some more here, trying to get 4 cards besides each other, only goot 3 now and 1 below, probably cuz of the width or something, you see anything here i could adjust?

```
.container {
position: relative;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 1500px;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

}

```
.container .card {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    background: #3f3f3f;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px gray;
}
```

Comment: Please add the HTML and the rest of your reproducible code, so that anyone may be able to diagnose your problem

Comment: please add a full minimal reproduciable code snipper (ctrl + M). I single CSS line wont get you far. Beside of that, body is the ultimate parent of all content. You cant place anything above the body or below it. But you proberly also want to read into: `flex-direction: column;`. The default value for `flex-direction` is `row`

Comment: Ahh!! You are completley right @Johannes, put it all in a main tag instead and now everything is where it should be.

Comment: @tacoshy, thx a lot! flex-direction: column really did the job for my headers outside the container after i put them in a main tag. Thx a lot! Just last thing, I have 4 cards inside the container which i want them to be besides eachother, now there is three on a row and one below, probably something with the width to to is my guess, without you seeing the code, any ideas? otherwise I send it all here :D

Comment: .container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 1500px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container .card {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    background: #3f3f3f;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px gray;
}

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't apply flex to `body`, but only to the element (for example "main" or similar) where you really need it, otherwise you get the effect described, i.e. *every* element in the body becomes a flex item.